# jpackage fails on Mac OS 11.2

Tags: java, jpackage, java-15

I have `Mac OS 11.2` and `Openjdk 15.0.1`.
I run `jpackage`, but when I use option `--license-file license.txt`
the package is build (but without license) and I have an error in the command line:

```
java.io.IOException: Command [/usr/bin/hdiutil, unflatten, /Users/myproject/package-1.0.dmg] exited with 1 code
```

Why it is failing and how can I fix it?